# PostgreSQL Compare value from row to value in next row (different column)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, compare, rows

I have a table of encounters called user_dates that is ordered by 'user' and 'start' like below. I want to create a column indicating whether an encounter was followed up by another encounter within 30 days. So basically I want to go row by row checking if "encounter_stop" is within 30 days of "encounter_start" in the following row (as long as the following row is the same user).

```
user   |  encounter_start  | encounter_stop
    A  |  4-16-1989        | 4-20-1989
    A  |  4-24-1989        | 5-1-1989
    A  |  6-14-1993        | 6-27-1993
    A  |  12-24-1999       | 1-2-2000
    A  |  1-19-2000        | 1-24-2000
    B  |  2-2-2000         | 2-7-2000
    B  |  5-27-2001        | 6-4-2001
```

I want a table like this:

```
user   |  encounter_start  | encounter_stop | subsequent_encounter_within_30_days
    A  |  4-16-1989        | 4-20-1989      | 1
    A  |  4-24-1989        | 5-1-1989       | 0
    A  |  6-14-1993        | 6-27-1993      | 0
    A  |  12-24-1999       | 1-2-2000       | 1
    A  |  1-19-2000        | 1-24-2000      | 0
    B  |  2-2-2000         | 2-7-2000       | 1
    B  |  5-27-2001        | 6-4-2001       | 0
```

Comment: To offset rows there are only two possibilities: `lead\lag` analytic functions or subquery to the same table with inequality predicate (`>=`). Please, show what did you try so far and what was the issue with your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can `select..., exists <select ... criteria>`, that would return a boolean (always true or false) but if really want 1 or 0 just cast the result to integer: true=>1 and false=>0. See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=338e441bff3f8f388c884c01942737a4)

```
select ts1.user_id
     , ts1.encounter_start 
     , ts1. encounter_stop  
     , (exists ( select null
                  from test_set ts2 
                 where ts1.user_id = ts2.user_id 
                   and ts2.encounter_start 
                       between ts1.encounter_stop 
                          and (ts1.encounter_stop + interval '30 days')::date 
               )::integer  
       ) subsequent_encounter_within_30_days 
  from test_set ts1
 order by user_id, encounter_start;
```

Difference: The above (and demo) disagree with your expected result:  
B    |    2-2-2000 |   2-7-2000|   1  
subsequent_encounter (last column) should be 0. This entry starts and ends in Feb 2000, the other B entry starts In May 2001. Please explain how these are within 30 days (other than just a simple typo that is).

Caution: Do not use **user** as a column name. It is both a Postgres and SQL Standard [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-keywords-appendix.html). You can sometimes get away with it or double quote it. If you double quote it you MUST always do so. The big problem being it has a predefined meaning (run `select user;`) and if you forget to double quote is does not necessary produce an error or exception; it is much worse - *wrong results*.